# tan in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

tan(5.3) = 0.09276719520463

but in javascript:

Math.tan(5.3) = -1.50127339580693

how do i calculate Math.tan(something) in javascript in the deg mode?

Comment: Technically tan(5.3) is *not* 0.092767...; tan(5.3°) is 0.092767... -- if you are using degrees (or gradians), you have to specify them.

Answer (score 29):

Instead of writing a wrapper function for it (and taking a performance hit), you can multiply by these constants:

```
var deg2rad = Math.PI/180;
var rad2deg = 180/Math.PI;
```

And then use them like so:

```
var ratio   = Math.tan( myDegrees * deg2rad );
var degrees = Math.atan( ratio ) * rad2deg;
```

JavaScript deals only in radians, both as arguments and return values. It's up to you to convert them as you see fit.

Also, note that if you're trying to find the degrees of rotation for xy coordinates, you should use `Math.atan2` so that JavaScript can tell which quadrant the point is in and give you the correct angle:

```
[ Math.atan( 1/ 1), Math.atan2( 1, 1) ]; // [  45,  45 ]
[ Math.atan( 1/-1), Math.atan2( 1,-1) ]; // [ -45, 135 ]
[ Math.atan(-1/ 1), Math.atan2(-1, 1) ]; // [ -45, -45 ]
[ Math.atan(-1/-1), Math.atan2(-1,-1) ]; // [  45,-135 ]
```

Answer (score 11):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/tan

```
function getTanDeg(deg) {
   var rad = deg * Math.PI/180;
   return Math.tan(rad)
}
```

Comment: In other words convert the degrees to radians.

Answer (score 6):

So hard to find !

To accomplish basic [triangle math](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-finding-angle-right-triangle.html) in JavaScript, use ..

```
Math.atan(opposite/adjacent) * 180/Math.PI
```